# How to parse output from a command in OS X Automator?

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, script

I have the following code in Automator but it fails to load the variable with the output from the command.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    output = hdiutil verify "$f"
    echo "$output" 
done
```

I want to parse the output of that to see if it's verified or not however the variable is coming back empty.

Comment: How are you declaring a variable with the @ symbol?  Can you post how your variables are defined.

Comment: @tron $@ is how Automator passes input to shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
output=$(hdiutil verify "$f")
echo "$output"
```

Comment: No, this still results in an empty variable.

Comment: @iceberg Oops, fixed—had spaces either side of the equals.